# Favorite/star/bookmark toggle button in Extjs

Tags: button, extjs, bookmarks, favorites

How can I have toggle star-shaped button in Extjs, so when the state is 'pressed' it appears like a filled star, and otherwise like an outlined star?

For example, like the star that appears in Google chrome address bar to bookmark the page:

[image]

and when it is clicked it changes it appearance to [image]

or it could be a heart [image] that changes to

[image]

Or in gmail [image]

Comment: May you present some screenshots?

Comment: Sure, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

For panel header:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Sample Panel',
            tools: [{
                glyph: 'xf005@FontAwesome',
                pressed: false,
                callback: function () {
                    if (this.pressed) {
                        this.setGlyph('xf005@FontAwesome'); // star
                    } else {
                        this.setGlyph('xf006@FontAwesome'); // star-o
                    }
                    this.pressed = !this.pressed;
                }
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

And the font awesome style for index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: Hello Arthur, your screenshot looks great, but when I run your code in fiddle, it doesn't work. It just shows a panel with a rectangular icon. I also tried to include index.html from Manuel's solution, but simple nothing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: Include the font-awesome css in the index.html <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

Comment: Look in the api api play with css.

Comment: When I run your code in Fiddle it is ok, but when I implement it in my application it is not working. I got error message Uncaught TypeError: this.setGlyph is not a function.

Comment: Check the class Ext.getClassName(this).. check the version, use scope: this (look in the doc). Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this error.

Comment: I've found out that setGlyph method isn't supported in extjs versions below 6.5 (and I'm using 6.0.1). I further found out that setGlyph is a method  inside 'Ext.Glyph' class, so I copied that class inside my \ext\classic\classic\src\ folder, but I got the same error. Any ideas how I can overcome this problem?

Comment: You can try to upgrade the framework to >v6.5

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use viewmodel binding to `iconCls`. Each button has the config: `enableToggle: true` and it will publishe its pressed-state to the parent-viewModel. Use the bind expression of `iconCls: '{theButton.pressed?"fas fa-star":"far fa-star"}'` to make it work.

(also integrated FontAwesome5)

Here is the Link to a [Sencha-Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3aru)

The code:

```
    Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            layout: 'vbox',
            viewModel: {}, // <-- important
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Bookmark',
                enableToggle: true,
                bind: {
                    iconCls: '{theButton.pressed?"fas fa-star":"far fa-star"}',
                },
                reference: 'theButton',
                handler: function (button) {
                    if (button.pressed) {
                        Ext.toast({
                            html: 'pressed state',
                            title: 'The button was clicked...',
                            width: 250,
                            align: 't'
                        });
                    } else {
                        Ext.toast({
                            html: 'unpressed state',
                            title: 'The button was clicked...',
                            width: 250,
                            align: 't'
                        });
                    };

                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Manuel. Your code is very helpful to me, although I would prefer to have a button with transparent background that I can put in panel header - something like a clickable icon. Apart from that, your code raised a new question, and i would like to ask you for additional explanation. I know what ternary operator means iconCls: '{theButton.pressed?"fas fa-star":"far fa-star"}', but I am generally very confused when I can mix classic javascript commands with this json syntax with commas. For example, can I put somethig like text: '(1>0)?"bla bla bla":"jaja"'     for text button?

Comment: generally you can bind the text-property to button, yes. You can bind most (but not all) properties.  You should of course be aware that it is important to craft a valid bind expression. Just saying, because your last example is not valid.  https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.app.ViewModel.html

`bind: { text: '{theButton.pressed?"PRESSED":"UNPRESSED"}' }`